# Undefined reference error when link to Saxon library in C++

Tags: c++, makefile, linker-errors, qmake, saxon-c

I download the latest SaxonC-HE for Linux library from https://www.saxonica.com/download/c.xml

Then from the above website, I follow copy libsaxon-hec-12.4.1 to /usr/local/lib
And start writing code. When compile the code in C++, I got error:

Undefined reference to 'SaxonProcessor::newXQueryProcessor' etc

In my qmake file, I add LIBS += -lsaxon-hec-12.4.1

Pseudo code:

```
#include SaxonProcessor.h
SaxonProcess *processor = new SaxonProcessor(false);
XQueryProcessor *query = processor->newXQueryProcessor();
query->setQueryContent(content);
query->setParameters(parameter, XdmValue);
const char *result = query->runQueryToString();
```

I am wondering if I need to compile the saxonc library myself and generate lib files so I can link to. But there is no make file from the downloaded SaxonC folder

Comment: What platform are you on? Did you follow all instructions in https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/documentation12/index.html#!starting/installing and https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/documentation12/index.html#!starting/running, i.e. have you tried to build the samples?

Comment: I am using debian 12, I followed the instruction. I copied the libsaxon-eec-12.0.so to /usr/local/lib. I tried to compile the cppTests, having an error when compile SaxonCGlue. error: dangling pointer 'parameter' to 'temp' maybe used. But I do not think this related to the linking error I have in my code.

Comment: In your question you say you use HE, why does your comment say you copied the EE library? Did you set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`? So the samples in cppTests do not even build on Debian 12?

Comment: where did I say EE? I did not set ld library path, because the /usr/local/lib already exposed. Yes, it failed to build, but the error is different.

Comment: Oh, I see, I just copied the lib from the document you gave. The lib I have is libsaxon-hec-12.4.1.so

Comment: I will try to investigate why building the cppTests samples under Debian 12 fails.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I think the error is on SaxonCGlue.c, line 166, 167 and line 195, 196. It is  dangling pointer error. I think it is because line 160 and line 187 the parameters is freed, but some other pointer still reference to it. But when I include Saxon and link to Saxon in my code, I just need to link to the libsaxon-hec-12.4.1.so? Seems the error I had is I did not link to SaxonProcessor.

Comment: I have managed to build and run the cppTests sample under Debian 12 by adding `-Wno-error=dangling-pointer` in the shell script used to build the samples. I am afraid I don't know much specifically about qmake, so I can't help on that. As for your whole question on that problem, there have been no comments explaining why but there are downvotes and a closing attempt, try to edit it to provide more details to allow others to reproduce/understand the problem.

Comment: It is same idea as how you write make or cmake. The undefined reference error is usually you did not link to the right lib in your make file. But from the Saxon I downloaded, I only have one lib file, and according to Saxon document, I need to copy this lib into my local folder. And since there is no make file in Saxon I downloaded, I cannot compile the code and generate more lib files. So from my understanding I can only link to this lib from my make file.

Comment: And I provide my code, it is just a very basic code, set processor, set query, set external variables, and execute the query. I do not think the error is related with the code, it is a linking error, I think you have to link to the right lib in your make file. But Saxon only provide one lib, and since there is no make file for me to compile and generate new libs, the only lib I can link is libsaxon-hec-12.4.1.so

Comment: See my answer (has too much details to put into comments), the samples and there build shell script should show you which files to compile first and then link to and which ones to include to be able to run XQuery with SaxonC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the error by adding saxon source files into my project.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you look at the samples then you will certainly see, that to compile e.g. `testXQuery.cpp`, the build64-linux.sh file compiles a lot of files from `Saxon.C.API` before and links them, i.e. in https://saxonica.plan.io/projects/saxonmirrorhe/repository/he/revisions/he_mirror_saxon_12_4_1/entry/src/main/c/samples/cppTests/build64-linux.sh you see

```
#!/bin/sh

#Build file for SaxonC on C++


export SAXON_ERRORS="-Wall -Werror -Wextra"


export TURN_ERRORS_TO_WARNINGS="-Wno-error=sizeof-pointer-memaccess -Wno-error=unused-value -Wno-error=extra -Wno-error=reorder -Wno-error=sign-compare -Wno-error=unused-variable -Wno-error=unused-parameter -Wno-error=return-type -Wno-error=unused-but-set-variable"

rm -r bin
mkdir -p bin

gcc -m64  -g   -fPIC -I../../Saxon.C.API/graalvm -c ../../Saxon.C.API/SaxonCGlue.c -o bin/SaxonCGlue.o -ldl -lc -lsaxon-@@edition@@c-@@VERSION@@ $TURN_ERRORS_TO_WARNINGS $SAXON_ERRORS $1 $2

gcc -m64  -g  -fPIC  -I../../Saxon.C.API/graalvm -c ../../Saxon.C.API/SaxonCXPath.c -o bin/SaxonCXPath.o -ldl -lc -lsaxon-@@edition@@c-@@VERSION@@ $TURN_ERRORS_TO_WARNINGS $SAXON_ERRORS $1 $2



#g++  -std=c++14 -fPIC -m64  -g  -c cppExtensionFunction.cpp -o bin/cppExtensionFunction.o $TURN_ERRORS_TO_WARNINGS $SAXON_ERRORS $1 $2
g++ -std=c++14 -m64  -g  -fPIC -I../../Saxon.C.API/graalvm  -c ../../Saxon.C.API/XdmValue.cpp -o bin/XdmValue.o -ldl -lc -lsaxon-@@edition@@c-@@VERSION@@ $TURN_ERRORS_TO_WARNINGS $SAXON_ERRORS $1 $2

g++ -std=c++14 -m64  -g  -fPIC -I../../Saxon.C.API/graalvm  -c ../../Saxon.C.API/XdmItem.cpp -o bin/XdmItem.o -ldl -lc -lsaxon-@@edition@@c-@@VERSION@@ $TURN_ERRORS_TO_WARNINGS $SAXON_ERRORS $1 $2



g++  -std=c++14 -m64  -g  -fPIC -I../../Saxon.C.API/graalvm  -c ../../Saxon.C.API/XdmNode.cpp -o bin/XdmNode.o -ldl -lc -lsaxon-@@edition@@c-@@VERSION@@ $TURN_ERRORS_TO_WARNINGS $SAXON_ERRORS $1 $2

g++ -std=c++14 -m64  -g  -fPIC -I../../Saxon.C.API/graalvm -c ../../Saxon.C.API/XdmMap.cpp -o bin/XdmMap.o -ldl -lc -lsaxon-@@edition@@c-@@VERSION@@ $TURN_ERRORS_TO_WARNINGS $SAXON_ERRORS $1 $2

g++ -std=c++14 -m64  -g  -fPIC -I../../Saxon.C.API/graalvm -c ../../Saxon.C.API/XdmArray.cpp -o bin/XdmArray.o -ldl -lc -lsaxon-@@edition@@c-@@VERSION@@ $TURN_ERRORS_TO_WARNINGS $SAXON_ERRORS $1 $2

g++ -std=c++14 -m64  -g   -fPIC -I../../Saxon.C.API/graalvm -c ../../Saxon.C.API/XdmFunctionItem.cpp -o bin/XdmFunctionItem.o -ldl -lc -lsaxon-@@edition@@c-@@VERSION@@  $TURN_ERRORS_TO_WARNINGS $SAXON_ERRORS $1 $2

g++  -std=c++14 -m64  -g  -fPIC -I../../Saxon.C.API/graalvm  -c ../../Saxon.C.API/XdmAtomicValue.cpp -o bin/XdmAtomicValue.o -ldl -lc -lsaxon-@@edition@@c-@@VERSION@@  $TURN_ERRORS_TO_WARNINGS $SAXON_ERRORS $1 $2

g++  -std=c++14 -m64  -g  -fPIC -I../../Saxon.C.API/graalvm  -c ../../Saxon.C.API/DocumentBuilder.cpp -o bin/DocumentBuilder.o -ldl -lc -lsaxon-@@edition@@c-@@VERSION@@  $TURN_ERRORS_TO_WARNINGS $SAXON_ERRORS $1 $2

g++  -std=c++14 -m64  -g  -fPIC -I../../Saxon.C.API/graalvm  -c ../../Saxon.C.API/SaxonProcessor.cpp -o bin/SaxonProcessor.o -ldl -lc -lsaxon-@@edition@@c-@@VERSION@@  $TURN_ERRORS_TO_WARNINGS $SAXON_ERRORS $1 $2

g++ -std=c++14 -m64  -g  -fPIC  -I../../Saxon.C.API/graalvm -c ../../Saxon.C.API/SaxonApiException.cpp -o bin/SaxonApiException.o -ldl -lc -lsaxon-@@edition@@c-@@VERSION@@  $TURN_ERRORS_TO_WARNINGS $SAXON_ERRORS $1 $2

g++  -std=c++14 -m64  -g  -fPIC -I../../Saxon.C.API/graalvm  -c ../../Saxon.C.API/Xslt30Processor.cpp -o bin/Xslt30Processor.o -ldl -lc -lsaxon-@@edition@@c-@@VERSION@@  $TURN_ERRORS_TO_WARNINGS $SAXON_ERRORS $1 $2

g++ -std=c++14 -m64  -g   -fPIC -I../../Saxon.C.API/graalvm -c ../../Saxon.C.API/XsltExecutable.cpp -o bin/XsltExecutable.o -ldl -lc -lsaxon-@@edition@@c-@@VERSION@@  $TURN_ERRORS_TO_WARNINGS $SAXON_ERRORS $1 $2

g++  -std=c++14 -m64  -g  -fPIC -I../../Saxon.C.API/graalvm  -c ../../Saxon.C.API/XQueryProcessor.cpp -o bin/XQueryProcessor.o -ldl -lc -lsaxon-@@edition@@c-@@VERSION@@  $TURN_ERRORS_TO_WARNINGS $SAXON_ERRORS $1 $2

g++  -std=c++14 -m64  -g  -fPIC -I../../Saxon.C.API/graalvm  -c ../../Saxon.C.API/XPathProcessor.cpp -o bin/XPathProcessor.o -ldl -lc -lsaxon-@@edition@@c-@@VERSION@@  $TURN_ERRORS_TO_WARNINGS $SAXON_ERRORS $1 $2

g++  -std=c++14 -m64  -g  -fPIC -I../../Saxon.C.API/graalvm  -c ../../Saxon.C.API/SchemaValidator.cpp -o bin/SchemaValidator.o -ldl -lc -lsaxon-@@edition@@c-@@VERSION@@  $TURN_ERRORS_TO_WARNINGS $SAXON_ERRORS $1 $2
```

and then

```
g++  -std=c++14 -m64  -g  -fPIC -I../../Saxon.C.API/graalvm bin/SaxonCGlue.o bin/SaxonCXPath.o bin/SaxonProcessor.o bin/XQueryProcessor.o bin/Xslt30Processor.o bin/XsltExecutable.o bin/XPathProcessor.o bin/DocumentBuilder.o bin/XdmValue.o bin/XdmItem.o bin/XdmNode.o bin/XdmAtomicValue.o bin/XdmArray.o bin/XdmFunctionItem.o bin/XdmMap.o bin/SchemaValidator.o bin/SaxonApiException.o testXQuery.cpp -o testXQuery -ldl -lc -lsaxon-@@edition@@c-@@VERSION@@  $TURN_ERRORS_TO_WARNINGS $SAXON_ERRORS $1 $2
```

and the file https://saxonica.plan.io/projects/saxonmirrorhe/repository/he/revisions/he_mirror_saxon_12_4_1/entry/src/main/c/samples/cppTests/testXQuery.cpp has e.g.

```
#include "../../Saxon.C.API/SaxonProcessor.h"
#include "../../Saxon.C.API/XdmArray.h"
#include "../../Saxon.C.API/XdmAtomicValue.h"
#include "../../Saxon.C.API/XdmFunctionItem.h"
#include "../../Saxon.C.API/XdmItem.h"
#include "../../Saxon.C.API/XdmMap.h"
#include "../../Saxon.C.API/XdmNode.h"
#include "../../Saxon.C.API/XdmValue.h"
#include "CppTestUtils.h"
#include <string>
```

That should show you which files to compile and then link to to run XQuery with SaxonC.

Comment: Hi, I made my code compile by adding the saxon source files into my project.
It just feel strange, because usually there should be a make file and you compile it and generate libs and you link to the lib you need from your project.

Comment: Yes I agree. Since the release of SaxonC 12 this should be now possible to reinstate. I have created the bug issue to track this request https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/6299

Comment: Btw when I use Saxon to process xquery in my code.
I get an error says I need to set an aboslute URI.
If you still remember in my other stackoverflow question, I give xml path into xquery variable, it is an absolute path to the xml file.
So when I set baseURI, I did like this: query->setQueryBaseURI("file://");
Then I get an exception says Expect authority at index 7: file://.
What should I fix?

Comment: @FeiSu, can you raise that as a separate, new question? It doesn't make sense to try to cover/answer such stuff in comment to an answered question, just because it happens to be in the context of the same product. Generally, a base URI, as a `file:` URI, in the context of a Linux file system, is more like `file:/dir/subdir/foo`.

Comment: There are also examples in the testXQuery.cpp sample I pointed you to earlier, see https://saxonica.plan.io/projects/saxonmirrorhe/repository/he/revisions/he_mirror_saxon_12_4_1/entry/src/main/c/samples/cppTests/testXQuery.cpp#L362

Comment: Hi, thanks, I change the uri to file:/ and it works. Thanks！